# Pull min and max value from CSV file

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a CSV file like:

```
123,hat,19.99
321,cap,13.99
```

I have this code:

```
 products_file = File.open('text.txt')
 while ! products_file.eof?
 line = products_file.gets.chomp
 puts line.inspect
 products[ line[0].to_i] = [line[1], line[2].to_f]
   end
 products_file.close
```

which is reading the file. While it's not at the end of the file, it reads each line. I don't need the `line.inspect` in there. but it stores the file in an array inside of my products hash.

Now I want to pull the min and max value from the hash.
My code so far is:

```
  read_file = File.open('text.txt', "r+").read
   read_file.(?) |line|
   products[ products.length] = gets.chomp.to_f
   products.min_by { |x| x.size }
   smallest = products
  puts "Your highest priced product is #{smallest}"
```

Right now I don't have anything after `read_file.(?) |line|` so I get an error. I tried using `min` or `max` but neither worked.

Comment: First, use the built-in [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/index.html) class to properly read CSV files. It can return an array for each line in the file, making it easy to grab the fields.

Answer (score 4):

**Without using CSV**

If I understand your question correctly, you don't have to use `CSV` class methods: just read the file (less header) into an array and  determine the min and max as follows:

```
arr = ["123,hat,19.99", "321,cap,13.99",
       "222,shoes,33.41", "255,shirt,19.95"]

arr.map { |s| s.split(',').last.to_f }.minmax
  #=> [13.99, 33.41]
```

or

```
arr.map { |s| s[/\d+\.\d+$/].to_f }.minmax
  #=> [13.99, 33.41]
```

If you want the associated records:

```
arr.minmax_by { |s| s.split(',').last.to_f }
  => ["321,cap,13.99", "222,shoes,33.41"]
```

**With CSV**

If you wish to use `CSV` to read the file into an array:

```
arr = [["123", "hat",   "19.99"],
       ["321", "cap",   "13.99"],
       ["222", "shoes", "33.41"],
       ["255", "shirt", "19.95"]]
```

then

```
arr.map(&:last).minmax
  # => ["13.99", "33.41"]
```

or

```
arr.minmax_by(&:last)
  #=> [["321", "cap",   "13.99"],
  #    ["222", "shoes", "33.41"]]
```

if you want the records. Note that in the CSV examples I didn't convert the last field to a float, assuming that all records have two decimal digits.

Comment: The fact that there is a `minmax_by(&block)` method is crazy and awesome.

Comment: @Devon, so much of Ruby seems crazy and awesome, but over time more and more of it becomes just the tools of the trade. I recall being blown away by `each_with_object([])` when I first saw it, as a kid. Fortunately, there's always more crazy and awesome stuff to learn.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the built-in CSV class as such:

```
require 'CSV'

data = CSV.read("text.txt")

data.sort!{ |row1, row2| row1[2].to_f <=> row2[2].to_f }

least_expensive = data.first
most_expensive = data.last
```

The `Array#sort!` method modifies `data` in place, so it is sorted based on the condition in the block for later usage. As you can see, the block sorts based on the values in each row at index 2 - in your case, the prices. Incidentally, you don't need to convert these values to floats - strings will sort the same way. Using `to_f` stops working if you have leading non-digit characters (eg, `$`), so you might find it better just keep the values as strings during your sort.

Then you can grab the most and least expensive, or the 5 most expensive, or whatever, at your leisure.

Comment: You don't need to convert the price to a float as long as all prices have two decimal digits, just `sort_by(&:last)`.  Sorting is expensive, however, compared to `min` and `max` or `minmax`.

Comment: I agree with @CarySwoveland that this is unnecessarily expensive. It does give you a bit more to work with than just finding the largest and smallest, though, if your application needs it.

Comment: @steenslag, yes on `minmax_by`. It's in my answer.